# urllib2 gives HTTP Error 400: Bad Request for certain urls, works for others

Tags: python, http, url, urllib2

I'm trying to do a simple HTTP get request with Python's urllib2 module.  It works sometimes, but other times I get `HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`.  I know it's not an issue with the URL, because if I use `urllib` and simply do `urllib.urlopen(url)` it works fine - but when I add headers and do `urllib2.urlopen()` I get Bad Request on certain sites.

Here is the code that's not working:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re,sys,urllib,urllib2

url = "http://www.gamestop.com/"

headers = {'User-Agent:':'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = urllib2.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req,None)
html1 = response.read()
```

(gamestop.com is an example of a URL that does not work)

Some different sites work, some don't, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Am I missing some important headers?  Making the request incorrectly?  Using the wrong User-Agent? (I also tried using the exact User-Agent of my browser, and that didn't fix anything)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You've got an extra colon in your headers.

```
headers = { 'User-Agent:': 'Mozilla/5.0' }
```

Should be:

```
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' }
```

Comment: Wow.  Yup, that was the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tom: Welcome to StackOverflow. "Wow. Yup, that was the issue. Thanks!" is best expressed "[by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)".